# compact subset of infinite-dimensional inner product space has empty interior

Tags: general-topology, inner-products

Could any one help me to show that every compact subset of infinite-dimensional inner product space $X$ has empty interior. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If $K$ is compact and if it has an interior point $x$ then $\overset  {-}{B}(x,r) \subset K$ for some $r>0$. This close ball is then compact. The closed unit ball is teh image of this closed ball undet the homeomorphism $y \to \frac 1 r (y-x)$. Hence the closed unit ball is compact which implies that the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: Why is the closed ball $\overline{B}(x,r)$ then compact?

Comment: Because a closed subset of a compact space is always compact.

Comment: Just a note, this argument breaks down if we instead equip the ambient space with the weak$^{\star}$ topology.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it by contradiction. Let $K$ be the compact and suppose $x_0$ is an interior point. Then there exists a ball $B(x_0,r)\subset K$, with $r>0$. Let $e_1,e_2,\dots$ an infinite orthonormal system (we know there are infinitely many linearly independent vectors and we can orthonormalize them using the Hilbert-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure). Then the infinitely many different points (vectors) $x_0+\frac{r}{2}e_i$ are in $B(x_0,r)$ (hence in $K$) within a distance from each other $r\sqrt{2}/2$ by Pythagorean Theorem. As a consequence, your set $K$ does not admit, say, a finite  $r\sqrt{2}/4$- net and is not compact (compact = totally bounded + complete in any metric space). Conclusion: your set does not have interior points.

Comment: You measure distance in an unknown space with unknown metric; I don't think you can do that.

Comment: The distance is, as usual in an inner product space, the one induced by the inner product, that is, $d(x,y)^2=\langle x-y,x-y\rangle$. That is why you can use Pythagorean Theorem, etc. In reality you do not need that much. The theorem is true in any normed space: the unit ball is compact iff it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Another question: could you clarify what you mean by $r\sqrt{2}/4$-net and why this implies that $K$ is not compact?

Comment: An $\epsilon$-net for $K$ is a subset of points such that the whole $K$ is contained in the union of the balls of radius $\epsilon$ centered at those points. If a set admits a  finite $\epsilon$-net for each positive $\epsilon$, it is called totally bounded.Total boundedness is a stronger requirement than just boundedness. The characterization of compact subsets of a metric space is s follows: $K$ is compact iff it is totally bounded and  complete (as a metric subspace). A way to prove that something is not compact is by proving that it is not totally bounded.